# How to do perf analysis in React 16

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, web

The React docs state that react-addons-perf does not work with React 16, but that [Chrome's built-in tools provide equivalent functionality](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#profiling-components-with-the-chrome-performance-tab). I have not found this to be the case.

For instance, let's say that I've made the classic mistake of not including a proper `key` on a list of elements ([demo code is on GitHub](https://github.com/NickHeiner/react-demo/tree/9a7666adbf0cdee26d25130e6f52d4f89ed81a03)):

```
  render() {

    const items = this.state.items.map((item, index) => <ListItem key={index} name={item.name} />)

    return <div>
      <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add item</button>
      <ul>{items}</ul>
    </div>;
  }
```

The `key={index}` issue will cause every `ListItem` to re-render when I add an item to the list. Using React 15 perf tools, I can easily discover this:

[image]

Once I apply the fix, I can see that the problem has gone away:

[image]

However, with React 16 and the Chrome dev tools, I'm not sure how to get equivalent information. ([Demo code with React 16](https://github.com/NickHeiner/react-demo/tree/8a5c20ba43c435b86fa67a5e49a0dfe4735870b1).) Here's the profiling results from when the bug was present:

[image]

And here are the profiling results from when the bug was absent:

[image]

I don't know how I'd look at these profiling results and get the same information that react-addons-perf was providing. And, my results don't look anything like the React docs:

[image]

I'm on Chrome 63.0.3239.108. Is the React team on a different version of Chrome, or do you need to enable special flags to make this work?

Potentially related: [How can I measure wasted renders in React 16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319184/how-can-i-measure-wasted-renders-in-react-16).

## tl;dr

- How can I get useful information from the Chrome profiler?
- Why do my profiler sessions look different from the React docs?

## Update

Thanks Rob. M! Turns out I was looking in the wrong tab in the dev tools. When I open the User Timing section, I see the difference between the good and the bad:

Bad, with many `ListItem` updates:

[image]

Good, with one `ListItem` update:

[image]

Comment: I think it looks different because you are viewing "Main", rather than "User Timing" - try expanding that section

Comment: That's correct! If you convert your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: What is the fix that you applied.

Answer (score 4):

React events are logged under the "User Timing" label - if you expand that label instead of "Main" you should find the component performance data you are looking for.

Comment: Screenshots appreciated.

Comment: I have this label called "Timings", I use Google Chrome 80.0.3987.106.